# Python Spreadsheet needs to output data based off of a column

Tags: python

I’m currently working with Python and Pandas to analyze a spreadsheet I’ve made. What i’m trying to accomplish is having a user input of a year, which will be from 1949-2022, and having the program rely on the spreadsheet to input the data from that year. There is one year column, and 5 data columns. How can I make it so the 5 data columns are outputted when a user inputs a value found in the year column?

Comment: will year value in the sheet be unique? i.e one row per year?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Gokulnath Yes, for example, 1949  is the first column in a row. The rest of the row is columns with data relating to that year.